# Android LinearLayout inside ScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I want to display 3 `GridView` in my `Layout`. I don't know how many elements are in each `GridView`, so the `Layout` should be `Scrollable`.

The problem is that the `Layout` does not `Scroll`, I can't see the third `GridView`.

Here is what I have done:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:text="Category 1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1sp"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="1sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"></GridView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="Category 2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1sp"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="1sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"></GridView>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="Category 3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1sp"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="1sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"></GridView>


        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Scroll Layout as the parent Layout. In other words swap it with Relative Layout.